# Sphere is a symplectic submanifold of Lie algebra $S0(3)^*$

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra, hamilton-equations, poisson-geometry

I'm working through this example in Peter Olver's textbook Application of Lie Groups to Differential equations and I am having some trouble and was wondering if somebody could point out where I went wrong.

[image]

So in the first highlighted section, I am trying to understand why this coincides with the tangent space of the sphere. I know that the Hamiltonian vectors are not linearly independent but atleast of them are so they span a $2D$ subspace in the tangent space, however, when we look at the tangent space to the sphere using spherical coordinates I get that it is spanned by
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} = -p\sin\theta\sin\phi \frac{d}{du^1} + p \cos\theta\sin\phi \frac{d}{du^2} = -u^2 \frac{d}{du^1} + u^1 \frac{d}{du^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{d\phi} = p\cos\theta\cos\phi \frac{d}{du^1} + p \sin\theta\cos\phi \frac{d}{du^2} - p\sin\phi \frac{d}{du^3}$$

Now the first one coincides with one of the Hamiltonian vectors however the second one I cannot seem to simplify or rewrite so that it looks like any of the other hamiltonian vectors or a linear combination of them.

As for the second highlited piece I wrote $ \phi = \arccos(\frac{u^3}{p})$ and $ \theta = \arctan(\frac{u^2}{u^1})$ by solving the spherical coordinates formulas and got the following by computing the gradient with respect to the coordinates $u = (u^1,u^2,u^3)$
$$\nabla_u(\theta) = (\frac{-u^2}{(u^1)^2 +(u^2)^2}, \frac{u^1}{(u^1)^2+(u^2)^2}, 0)$$
$$ \nabla_u(\phi) = (0,0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{(u^1)^2+ (u^2)^2}}) $$

$$\nabla_u(\theta) \times \nabla_u(\phi) = (\frac{-u^1}{((u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{-u^2}{((u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2)^{3/2}}, 0)$$
$$ u \cdot (\nabla_u(\theta) \times \nabla_u(\phi)) = (u^1,u^2,u^3) \cdot (\frac{-u^1}{((u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{-u^2}{((u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2)^{3/2}}, 0) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{(u^1)^2+(u^2)^2}}$$

Now changing that back into spherical coordinates I get
$$   u \cdot (\nabla_u(\theta) \times \nabla_u(\phi)) = \frac{-1}{p\sin\phi}$$
$$ \implies - u \cdot (\nabla_u(\theta) \times \nabla_u(\phi)) = \frac{1}{p\sin\phi} $$

So I am off by a negative sign, I've done the calculations over and I still get the same thing I am not sure where I am going wrong unless this whole process of doing the gradient was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:

> the second one I cannot seem to simplify or rewrite so that it looks like any of the other hamiltonian vectors or a linear combination of them.

In the $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ coordinates, you have expressed $\frac{d}{d\phi}$ as

$$ \frac{d}{d\phi} = \left( \rho \cos \theta \cos \phi, \; \rho \sin \theta \cos \phi, \; -\rho \sin \phi \right) $$

Using the coordinate-change formulas, you can write this in terms of the $u$'s as

$$ \frac{d}{d\phi} = \left( \frac{u_1u_3}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}}, \; \frac{u_2u_3}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}}, \; -\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2} \right) $$

You can check that this is expressible in terms of the $\hat{v}$'s by

$$ \frac{d}{d\phi} = \frac{u_2}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}} \, \hat{v}_1 - \frac{u_1}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}} \, \hat{v}_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}} \left( u_2 \hat{v}_1 - u_1 \hat{v}_2 \right) $$

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering how you reached this point? It doesn't seem too obvious to me. Did you just play around with the spherical equations or is there something else more obvious?

Comment: I noticed $\rho \cos \phi$ is in the first two expressions, and that is the expression for $u_3$, so I started by making that substitution. Then you can see that $\cos \theta = \frac{u_1}{\rho \sin \phi}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac{u_2}{\rho \sin \phi}$, so make that substitution. Finally, you can see that $\rho \sin \phi = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2}$ (it is the $r$ from polar coordinates). Lastly, I saw the $u_3$'s in $v_1$ and $v_2$ and just guessed what the coefficients would need to be to make the first and second coordinates work. Luckily, the third coordinate checks out.

Comment: Also, how did you get the first two coordinates of $\nabla \phi$ to be zero? You have $\phi = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{u_3}{\rho} \right)$, but remember that $\rho = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2}$, so it still depends on $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: I did notice that but I figured I could kind of ignore that since p is fixed ... and when I got a similar answer just with the negative sign flipped I figured it was alright and the negative sign error was computational but perhaps that is where my mistake lies.

Comment: +1 for answering what was actually asked, but it might also be worth mentioning that there is a simpler way of seeing that the the three given vectors lie in the tangent space to the sphere, namely that they are all orthogonal to the radially pointing vector $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$. (No need to use spherical coordinates.)